# Best value of an expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, functions, inequality

Hello during my work I come across this :

If $0\leq x<1$  a real number then :
$$\frac{x}{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}\leq \frac{\tanh(x)}{x}$$
So after a lot of works I finally find this for $0\leq x<1$  a real number:
$$\left(\frac{x}{\arctan(x)}\right)^{1/\alpha} +\frac{2}{\pi}- 1\leq \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x))}{\arctan(x)} \leq \left(\frac{x}{\arctan(x)}\right)^{1 /\beta} +\frac{2}{\pi}- 1$$
Here $\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{3}$

So my question is : What's the best value we can find for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem boils down to studying
$$ g(x) = \frac{\log\left[\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\tfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan x\right)}{\arctan(x)}+1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right]}{\log\left[\frac{x}{\arctan x}\right]}$$
over the interval $(0,1)$. It turns out to be a decreasing function, bounded between $0.252051697\ldots$ and $\frac{8}{\pi^3}$.

Comment: Many thanks so this the best value for my problem . For $0.252051697$ I find $(1/7)*7^{1/3}*Zeta(7)^{5/6}*Catalan$ with the [Calculator Plouffe](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) are you agree with this last fact ?

Comment: @FatsWallers: in explicit terms such constant is $$\frac{\log(\pi-2+2\log 3)-\log(\pi)}{\log(4)-\log(\pi)}=\lim_{x\to 1^-} g(x). $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(x,-\tanh{x})$, $B(x,\operatorname{arctanh}{x})$, $C(x,\tanh{x})$, $C'(\tanh{x},x)$ and $D(x,0)$.

Thus, since $\operatorname{arctanh}$ is a convex increasing function on $[0,1)$ and $C$ and $C'$  are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$, we obtain: $$\measuredangle BOA\geq\measuredangle C'OA=90^{\circ}.$$

Thus, $$OD^2\leq BD\cdot AD$$ or
$$x^2\leq\operatorname{arctanh}{x}\tanh{x}$$ and we are done!